# Splitting a file based on number of records and file size

Tags: linux, bash, split

I have a file which contains 100 records... Each record has different size, like some are 1 KB while some are 1 MB. I want to split the file based upon number of records, let's say 5. and each sub file should have maximum file size as 2 MB.
When we use the split command, we can use -b/C for giving the file size parameter and we can use -n to give the number of lines or records we want to use in each files. But in split we can only use either file size parameter or number of records parameter any one of them, not both.

Is there any way or any alternative of split, that I can use to achieve both? split a file into sub files, each containing less than or equal to 5 records/ lines or each sub file with less than or equal to 2 MB.

secanrios:

1. file with 5 records and size 2MB
2. file with 1 record and size 2 MB
3. file with 5 records and size 1 MB

> ```
> absacsacsa......                1 KB
> zzsasabsac......                1 MB
> absacsacsa......                2 KB
> zyasbsacsacsa......             2 MB
> cbsacsacsa......                1 B
> .
> .
> .
> ```

The real file has almost 3 million lines, so I cant use any manual approach, i.e checking each lines, reading file, etc as it takes hours to process. I'm just looking for some command like split which can take two parameters, split is quite fast, but unfortunately only takes single parameter.

Comment: There is no solution to your problem. If all records are 1MB any sub-file containing 5 records will be 5MB, that is more than 2MB. Please edit your question and explain which of your two constraints (5 records, less than 2MB) has the highest priority. As SO is not a free coding service please also show what you tried up to now, and explain why it did not work. You could also take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: You have to implement this explicitly, by reading the file line by line and summing up the number of the lines and the number of characters in each line.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for that, I have tried that solution. But since the records count are in millions. and its taking even 10-20 minutes to process only 10000 records. So i guess I cant go with manual approach. I'm still searching if theres any other way.

Comment: Every approach will need to read the file sequentially, unless you hire some magicians from Hogwarts castle. However, the speed will depend on how you read and process the records. If you write the loop in an inefficient way, it will take ages. `bash` is already not the ideal tool for this task, and if you do it in bash, make sure that you don't create any child process inside the loop body, as this will kill you. Since you did not show us how you processed the file, we can't say why it is so slow.

Comment: As a starting point for getting a reasonable time estimation, do a `wc -l` on your file. The time it takes, will be close to the time you can hope to achieve with a good manual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that "2MB" is 2000000, "records" are lines, the "size" of a "record" is the number of characters. It has been tested with GNU awk.

```
awk -v smax=2000000 -v lmax=5 -v n=0 -v c=0 -v name=xxx000000 '
  function next_file() {
    print name, n, sum
    close(name)
    c += 1
    name = sprintf("xxx%06d", c)
    n = 0
    sum = 0
  }
  sum + length($0) + 1 > smax {
    next_file()
  }
  {
    print > name
    n += 1
    sum += length($0) + 1
  }
  n == lmax {
    next_file()
  }
  END {
    if(n > 0) {
      print name, n, sum
    }
  }
' file
```

`smax` is the maximum size per file. `lmax` is the maximum number of lines per file. `n`, `sum` and `c` are internal variables used to count lines, compute cumulated sizes and count the created files.

This will create files named `xxx000000`, `xxx000001`... It will also print information on the standard output, one line per created file, with the file name, its line count and size:

```
xxx000000 5 1569851
xxx000001 4 1965155
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I'm actually looking for a command that can perform such operation, like split or csplit. Its a manual approach that you have provided. Since the data I'm having is in huge number, it will take so many minutes or perhaps hours. So i cant use manual approach, tried that and its takes 13 minutes to process only 10000 records. whereas if i use split command with single parameter it will take less than 10 seconds to process 2 million records.

Comment: This is not a _manual approach_, it is fully automated. Anyway, I do not know of an existing utility that does what you want. If this is too slow you will maybe have to code an equivalent algorithm in an efficient programming language (e.g., C or C++). Another option would be to split with one line per file with `split` and then concatenate files but I am almost sure that it will be even slower.

Comment: It would be nice to update your question and explain that you ask for an **existing** utility to which you will just pass options, not a script for a scriptable tool (`awk`, `perl`, ...). Also add maybe that you want a performance of about that number of seconds for a that large file, it will help those who try to answer.

Comment: I updated the `awk`-based solution to avoid some memory copies. It should be a bit faster. But don't expect a 10x speed-up.